# Node tls module not supported in browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, node.js, jspm, systemjs

I used jspm and SystemJS for load some node modules in npm. And one of them ([docker-api-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-api-wrapper)) that used [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module inside it. So that when I tried to run it on browser, it always threw an exception like

```js
Error loading "npm:docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9"
at http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9.js
  Error loading "npm:docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9"
from "js/site"
at http: //localhost:58063/js/site.js
  Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9/index.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9/lib/DockerApi.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/docker-api-wrapper@0.2.9/lib/utils.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/request@2.61.0.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/request@2.61.0/index.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/request@2.61.0/request.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/forever-agent@0.6.1.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/npm/forever-agent@0.6.1/index.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/github/jspm/nodelibs-tls@0.1.0.js
  uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/github/jspm/nodelibs-tls@0.1.0/index.js
  uncaught exception: Node tls module not supported in browsers.

es6 - mod...ader.js(line 7)
uncaught exception: Node tls module not supported in browsers.
uncaught exception: Error evaluating http: //localhost:58063/lib/github/jspm/nodelibs-tls@0.1.0/index.js
  uncaught exception: Node tls module not supported in browsers.
```

Could anyone help me on that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I see you already posted this [on the request issue tracker](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1748). I think it might not actually be supported. Try [`then-request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/then-request) instead